# How to trigger the scenario outlines with examples data mentioned in an external file- Cucumber JVM?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, browser-automation

I would like to trigger my scenario outline with data from an excel document instead of mentioning the data in the feature file. Is there any way to modify the examples data at run-time ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a scenario outline then there is no use of using excel. If you are using a excel then you have to reload the page for every record of test data whereas in scenario outline each record considered as different test case.
So my suggestion would be to specify data in feature file itself.